# Bombshell spy documents leaked to The Sun meanwhile previously appeared to

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> VLADIMIR Putin's health has "worsened" and he isn't eating as he suffers crippling stomach pains, it has been claimed.
> The tyrant, 70, is rumoured to be battling several health issues - with speculation fuelled by his often bloated look and twitching feet.
> Bombshell spy documents leaked to The Sun **meanwhile** previously appeared to confirm the dictator has pancreatic cancer and early-stage Parkinson's disease.
> It has now been claimed the Russian leader has suffered a setback in his health.

[Source](https://www.thesun.co.uk/news/21923861/putins-health-stomach-pains-isnt-eating/?utm_source=youtube&utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=sunyoutubestories%22)

---

The word *meanwhile* is used to compare two things, especially if they are completely different and are happening at the same time.
However, Is **meanwhile** being used to compare two things, when they are similar?

Comment: 'meanwhile previously' …written by an idiot. Don't read the Sun, you'll think the world is likely to end tomorrow. Its self-appointed job is to hand out opinion as though it was fact; to scare stupid people into irrational & often jingoistic thought and action.

Comment: 'previously appeared to confirm' = speculated wildly, yet will not admit they were just making it up. Really, avoid this paper. It's not good for your sanity.

Comment: I think it's just journalese (the formulaic language used by journalists), used as a meaningless linking word. "Meanwhile" is also commonly used in comic books to indicate a shift of location, which is another use of "meanwhile" as a connective without obvious comparison or juxtaposition.

Answer (score 2):

"Meanwhile" has a primary, literal meaning of "occurring at the same time", or "until something else happens".

> Carl's starting college in September. Meanwhile, he's travelling around Europe.
> (Source: https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/meanwhile)

There is a secondary meaning of "and yet", as in, roughly "even though it perhaps seems paradoxical, the following is also true"; but I don't think that's how it's being used here.

I don't think there is any sense of "comparison" in this example. "Meanwhile" is just a more emphatic way to say "and also" here.

Answer (score 1):

I think the sentence beginning with "Bombshell" and ending with "Parkinson's disease" has been lifted from another context and not edited properly to fill the role it was meant to play in this paragraph. This is why "meanwhile" seems out of place or confusing here.

I can only speculate on what they intended, but probably something like: "Meanwhile, bombshell spy documents previously leaked to The Sun appear to confirm the dictator has pancreatic cancer and early-stage Parkinson's disease."